# How to have 2 types on one Rails 4 input field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

In our Rails 4.2 app, there is a `hidden_file` field which we would like to be both :hidden and :file (type):

```
 <%= f.input :hidden_file, as: :file & :hidden %>
```

We tried:

```
 <%= f.input :hidden_file, as: [:file, :hidden] %>
```

It returns error:

```
undefined method `to_sym' for [:file, :hidden]:Array
```

The following only takes :hidden as option and left out :file :

```
 <%= f.input :hidden_file, as: :file, as: :hidden %>
```

What's the right way to has 2 options for `as:` (type)?

Comment: To do so makes no sense. If you want a hidden file field, make it a file field then hide it with CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the file input field inside a hidden div.

```
<div style="overflow: hidden;width:83px;">
   <input name="userfile" id="userfile" type="file"/>
</div>
```

You cannot put two types on an html field that I know of, at least that is my understanding from the [html spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.html#input)